# iphone 5 screen size and ratio problem

Tags: ios, iphone, screen-size

i am worry about the iphone 5 screen size will change to 4 inch or even change its ratio. i only use absolute value in my game, which apple recommends against.

```
mySprite.position = ccp(30, 50);//bad style, but i still use it
```

should be:

```
mySprite.position = ccp(screenSize.width / 15, screenSize.height / 20);
```

but i don't think i can change all of my code. so is it necessary for me to wait until iphone 5 & ios 5 comes out, and make both versions of them? 
maybe when iphone 5 comes out, all new apps should support both screen size. so should i make the app immediately before iphone 5 (since i don't think i can make a 'universal app') and hope that apple have a solution for old apps(like ipad 2x solution for iphone app)

Comment: Why don't you wait for the rumours to disappear first and wait and see if it is true??????

Comment: Yea to be fair there is no official posts/articles about the "iPhone 5". If the screen size changes, Apple are pretty good at supporting backwards compatibility. It may be that your app will no longer run on the new devices - but if that is the case, worry about it when it happens.

Comment: k, i guess i'll just start to make it now

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laying out & sizing of subviews in a UIViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037716/laying-out-sizing-of-subviews-in-a-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: While not an exact duplicate of this question, the above-linked one addresses the same core issue of relative layout that people have been concerned about since the launch of the original iPhone (there have been rumors of different screen sizes since day one).  See also some of the questions regarding Retina display support for ideas on how to prepare your code for any potential screen resolution or aspect ratio changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those people who vote down the answer, please check the date of the question (Sep 4'11, before the iPhone 4S published!), it's actually talking about the iPhone 4S and iOS 5 in 2011! Not the real iPhone 5 in 2012! People called the 5th generation iPhone "iPhone 5" at that time, Who knows why Apple called its 6th generation iPhone "iPhone 5"?

If you still want to vote it down, I am sorry that I didn't edit my answer about the iPhone 4S after ONE YEAR later.

---

Also, I edited the answer for the new iPhone 5 and iOS 6 in 2012:

You'd better use the main screen's size as the size of your RootViewController's view, and then use autoresizingMask (`view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` for example) to let all of your subviews automatically change its size or position.

Also if your App only supports iOS 6, then you can use the new Auto Layout as well.

Comment: it sounds reasonable, but a lot of rumors say that iphone 5 will change to edge-to-edge larger screen...anyway, guess apple won't let developers face this kind of hardware issue...hopefully

Comment: For those people who vote down the answer, please check the date of the question, it's actually talking about the iPhone 4S and iOS 5 in 2011! Not the real iPhone 5 in 2012!

And I am right about iPhone 4S that Apple did NOT changed the screen size! Please cancel your vote down.

Comment: Your original answer made no mention of the iPhone 4S whatsoever, it only said "iPhone 5", when it didn't even exist then. The problem was that you answered a speculative question with even more speculation (and a really complacent tone to boot).

Comment: No one knows what is the new iPhone's name until Apple released it to public. At that time (Sep 4' 2011), people called the 5th generation iPhone : "iPhone 5" as the comments right above yours. Who knows why Apple called its 6th generation iPhone "iPhone 5"? I am sorry that I didn't edit my answer about the iPhone 4S after ONE YEAR later. If you still want to vote it down, well, I have no words for you.

Comment: If "no one knows" about the new iPhone, please don't claim that you know anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the iPad - it has a different aspect ratio but still runs iPhone apps.

But @Lee Armstrong's comment is right - basing your app's design on devices that are just rumours probably isn't a good idea!

Answer (score -1):

The fact that people still use the ancient xib technology means you're safe. In xibs, all values are hardcoded as absolute points in the coordinate space. So if Apple releases a device with a different screen size, they can't assume apps for the old screen size will scale accordingly.

I don't know anything about the likelihood of a phone with a different screen size being released. But if they do, they will probably do something like they did on the iPad, where iPhone apps run in their original ratio and size.

Another important point is that apps very often have graphics in them that aren't stretchable. Think background patterns, gradients, custom buttons, etc.

Comment: While the "ancient xib technology" is based on work by NeXT, the XIB format has only been around since 2007, so that's perhaps not the right choice of words.  It's based on points, not pixels, so Interface Builder layouts can scale to new resolutions (see Retina display support on the iPhone 4).  Additionally, you can set up springs and struts constraints to autoresize and layout views with changes to subviews, so they can scale to new screen sizes.  See how this has been used for years on the Mac for variable windows sizes.