# Interface Orientation, Stretching and Aspect Ratio

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

```
-  (BOOL)    shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation 
          : (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
```

The above method works as expected in terms of letting a rotation to occur.  But I have a very hard time trying to make a UIView stretch while keeping its aspect ratio.

What happens is the UIView stretches horizontally while changing into landscape mode but it wouldn't stretch vertically no matter what I do.  In fact its height shrinks quite a bit in landscape mode.

Have tried the following settings in IB and in code but no use.

- In IB, have tried "Aspect Fit", "Aspect Fill" and the Autosizing Box
- In code, have tried "autosizingMask" and "setContentMode"

Hope somebody could help ...

Or please leave a note if you have done / encountered something similar.

Edit :

I think I found a solution from another SO question. What happened was my code got entangled with the effect of IB's AutoResizing features.  A link to the question can be found in my own answer.

Comment: This is already covered in following link - 

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325795/webview-resizes-automatically-to-portrait-and-landscape-view-in-iphone

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It may not apply to my situation since my UIView is created in IB.  But I will give it a try ...

Comment: Unfortunately, question 2325765's solution doesn't work for me. When the autoresizingMask is applied, the image would shrink even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the Content Mode (set with `setContentMode:` or by changing the View's Mode in IB) isn't going to be useful to you because what it controls is what happens to a view's content *in response to* a change in size—it doesn't control the actual size change. More over, unless you set it to `UIViewContentModeRedraw` the contents won't be redrawn, but rather just shifted or stretched, which generally isn't what you want.

On the other hand, setting the autosizing mask (or using the Autosizing Box in IB) doesn't get you what you want, either. `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` will change the width of the view in proportion to che change in its superview's size (using `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` and/or `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` in addition will control whether or not the distance to the sides of the screen stays constant). But the autoresizing mask doesn't give you a way to have the height changed *based on* the change in width: you can have it change in proportion to the superview's height and/or stick to the top/bottom.

So you'll have to manage the resizing yourself, programatically, in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`. Something like:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect rectToResizeTo;

    if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
        rectToResizeTo = CGRectMake(x1, y1, width1, height1);
    } else {
        rectToResizeTo = CGRectMake(x2, y2, width2, height2);
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.viewToResize.frame = rectToResizeTo;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  Will give it a try later today or tomorrow as I am running out of time at the moment.

Comment: I think your solution should work. But currently I am using one which partially relies on IB since it requires less change with my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a similar problem could find your answer in this another SO question : [Laying out & sizing of subviews in a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037716/laying-out-sizing-of-subviews-in-a-uiviewcontroller).