# Space between custom UITabBar and ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I took a regular `UITabBar` and changed it's background image to a custom one which has a lower height, so I changed the `height` of the `frame`.
At first what I got is a blank space below the tab bar. so I changed the `origin` of the `frame` too. But now the blank space has moved up above the tab bar and this is the result:

[image: space above tab bar]

And this is the code declaring the tab bar in the AppDelegate:

```
self.tabContoller = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
//customizing the tabbar
UIImage * tabBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarBg.png"];
self.tabContoller.tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245.f/255.f green:245.f/255.f blue:245.f/255.f alpha:255.f/255.f];
self.tabContoller.tabBar.backgroundImage = tabBackgroundImage;
//setting the tabbar height to the correct height of the image
CGRect tabR = self.tabContoller.tabBar.frame;
CGFloat diff = tabR.size.height - tabBackgroundImage.size.height;
tabR.size.height = tabBackgroundImage.size.height;
tabR.origin.y += diff;
self.tabContoller.tabBar.frame = tabR;
```

I guess that the problem is that the `ViewController`s draw themselves above a constant space which is the height of the regular tab bar. Is there any way to change it?

Comment: Try just by increasing the `height` of the `view` of the viewcontroller. If you can't form the xib, do it manually in the `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: That doesn't work, I even tried setting it in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`. it has no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your UITabBarController's subviews to a full-sized frame, this worked for me:

```
[[yourTabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

Comment: This doesn't work in iOS7, there seems to be something extra left behind.  The black rectangle goes away, but now there is a gray border where it used to be...

Answer (score 7):

Try creating your own class extending from UITabBar and use this function:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize auxSize = size;
    auxSize.height = 54; // Put here the new height you want and that's it
    return auxSize;
}
```

This will resize the UITabBar to the size you want. Simple and easy.

Comment: I'm surprised it took me so long to find this answer. It should be upvoted more. This really is the easiest way to do funky stuff to a UITabBar. Thank you.

Comment: This is literally the only way I've been able to get a custom height on a UITabBar.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the frame like @JoaT mentioned doesn't work make sure the view controller's view has the correct autoresizing mask set.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037716/laying-out-sizing-of-subviews-in-a-uiviewcontroller) link may be helpful.

Comment: I tried `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` and got no results. I also set those properties: `self.tabContoller.tabBar.autoresizesSubviews = YES;` and `self.tabContoller.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;` and it didn't help. Should I set it anywhere else?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the frame and bound size of the tab bar after the first view controller appears? Maybe it's not what we expect it to be after setting it in the app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I tried by changing the height and origin of tabbar, for me it worked properly.You can try by increasing the height of your viewcontroller.