# how can add space between two tabbar items of Custom tabbar in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing iPad app, in which am using a `UITabBarController`. How do I customize the space between the items?

I tried this code, but it is not working:

```
   self.window.rootViewController = self.tabContoroller;
   [tabContoroller setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-10, 1038, 54)];
```

[image]

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737420/space-between-custom-uitabbar-and-viewcontroller

Comment: any one pls help me out from this problem

Comment: http://code4app.net/category/tabbar/1

Answer (score 6):

For iOS 7 and above, you can now use the property `itemSpacing` in combination with `itemPositioning` set to `UITabBarItemPositioningCentered`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom tabbar controller from scratch. There are tons of good guides out there. This is one I found for you: [iOS Custom Tab Bar](http://rocksaucestudios.com/tapsauce/post/ios-custom-tab-bar/)

If you need further explanation of the code just edit this post and I'll check back on your progress.

Comment: `if (youCanDoItForiPhone && (you == developer)) { NSLog(@"You can do it for iPad, too.");}`

Comment: It's the same thing basically, you just need to follow that example but in your iPad app instead. And if you use ARC you need to convert that as well.

Comment: in my application am create custom navigation controller with tabbar so ,am create custom tabbar but action is not performing ..how can gve action to particular tabbar items?

Comment: Make sure you have connected the right outlets and set up your delegate correctly, otherwise your delegate methods won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

I just create a subclass of the tabbar and rewrite the layoutSubviews.

There is a property call [titlePositionAdjustment](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarItem/selectedImage). We can add space by changing the position.