# IOS swift View.frame.width is wrong

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

Hello i try to get the width of a UIView Element.

I tested it on an Iphone 4s Emulator.

I have an UIView Element on the main screen. Wich has 20 offset on the left and the right site of the screen.

When i call

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width = 320
```

but

```
viewGame.frame.width = 240
```

but width of viewGame should be 260 so how do i get the real frame width ?

Edit: i am using autolayout to align the view

Comment: Are you aligning the view to margins? That could explain the difference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

sorry for bothering. Just after posting this question i found the solution [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037716/laying-out-sizing-of-subviews-in-a-uiviewcontroller)

The problem is that i was calling my functions in the viewDidLoad() function in the view controller. But at this time the layouts havent been aranged yet.
Now i call my functions in the viewDidAppear() function and everything works fine

Comment: Take a look at viewDidLayoutSubviews as well :)

Comment: I did, but for some reason it got called multiple times, so i rather sticked to viewDidAppear() in hope it will always just get called one time

Comment: Yeah, if you're modifying the view within your function, I would expect that **viewDidLayoutSubviews()** gets called again. Glad you solved it!

Comment: You are a life saver! Thanks

Comment: so basically initially it has constant sizes based on your current selected device in storyboard, which is very ugly... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667820/frame-size-of-uicollectionview-is-bigger-than-size-of-uiscreen