# Frame size of UICollectionView is bigger than size of UIScreen

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, constraints, frame

In `viewDidLoad` func of my `UIViewController` I call

```
print("\(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width) \(collectionView.frame.width)")
```

and it prints

> 320.0 375.0

How is it possible? `UICollectionView` should has the same width, mb smaller but definitely not bigger

Settings of this view in storyboard:

[image]

each constraint set as

[image]

So I test it on iPhone SE Simulator but in Storyboard I have iPhone 8.

[image]

[image]

But I believe it should not matter at all when I use autolayout (constraints to make size of my view match size of safe area)

iPhone 8 width is 375 points and iPhone SE is 320:

[image]

**Update**

It seems `viewDidLoad` returns sizes of your last selected device in storyboard (quite ugly)

So to get correct data about views I have to get sizes in `viewDidAppear`

In Android if size of some view isn't available yet (view wasn't inflated yet) then it just returns zeros (width == 0, height == 0), but in iOS you get width and height from Xcode Storyboard in runtime... Really?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're instantiating a view controller from storyboard, the size of its view will be what is currently set on the storyboard. It will have the same size as the screen after it has been added to the view hierarchy. `viewDidLoad` is called before the view is added so it will still have the same size as on the storyboard. You can get the size it is displayed in inside methods, `viewWillApear`, `viewDidAppear`, and `viewDidLayout`. Just keep in mind that these methods might be called multiple times.

Comment: Yes.. already found out that. It's better to return zeros like in Android because many developers can think that sizes are correct in `viewDidLoad`, so it's designed very bad. In Android if size of some view isn't available yet (view wasn't inflated yet) then it just returns zeros (width == 0, height == 0), but in iOS you get width and height from last selected device in Xcode Storyboard in runtime (in viewDidLoad func)...

Comment: I think that might be problematic if you don't use Autolayout and just want your views to have the same size as what you've set in storyboard. I think storyboards and nibs are really just an archive to be consumed by `NSCoding` implementation of `UIKit` classes. So it makes some sense that whatever properties you set on them is reflected when you instantiate objects from storyboard.

Comment: well.. they could set zeros if constraints were used for a view and those constants instead of zeros if constraints weren't used (when they are same in viewDidLoad, viewWillApear, viewDidAppear and viewDidLayout)